# RPM build on Jenkins fails on a more recent mock version than mock on workstation that succeeds

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to build and deploy an RPM package from Jenkins based on some spec file boilerplate from another project that was written earlier than mine. For some reasons, I am getting build errors when I try to build or release this package from within Jenkins.

```
+ rm -rf /builddir/build/BUILDROOT/component-prefix-blah-api-proxy-0.1.0.16-1.bbc.el7.x86_64
BUILDSTDERR: ++ dirname /builddir/build/BUILDROOT/component-prefix-blah-api-proxy-0.1.0.16-1.bbc.el7.x86_64
RPM build errors:
BUILDSTDERR: error: File not found by glob: /builddir/build/BUILDROOT/component-prefix-blah-api-proxy-0.1.0.16-1.bbc.el7.x86_64/var/www/cgi-bin/*
BUILDSTDERR:     File not found by glob: /builddir/build/BUILDROOT/component-prefix-blah-api-proxy-0.1.0.16-1.bbc.el7.x86_64/var/www/cgi-bin/*
Child return code was: 1
EXCEPTION: [Error()]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mockbuild/trace_decorator.py", line 96, in trace
    result = func(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mockbuild/util.py", line 734, in do_with_status
    raise exception.Error("Command failed: \n # %s\n%s" % (command, output), child.returncode)
Error: Command failed: 
 # /usr/bin/systemd-nspawn -q -M b88888b933974fe283e8497d165b5369 -D /var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-9876/root --capability=cap_ipc_lock --bind=/tmp/mock-resolv.kXeD1i:/etc/resolv.conf --setenv=LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 --setenv=TERM=vt100 --setenv=SHELL=/bin/bash --setenv=HOSTNAME=mock --setenv=PROMPT_COMMAND=printf "\033]0;<mock-chroot>\007" --setenv=HOME=/builddir --setenv=PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin --setenv=PS1=<mock-chroot> \s-\v\$  -u mockbuild bash --login -c /usr/bin/rpmbuild -bb --target x86_64 --nodeps /builddir/build/SPECS/blah-api-proxy.spec
```

There is another error that came up earlier than the one above in the RPM build.log file that I do not think is the main error as I have seen this occur in other well-working builds before

```
BUILDSTDERR: Failed to create directory /var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-9876/root//sys/fs/selinux: Read-only file system
```

I have tried setting the --old-chroot flag on the execution of mock. However, I started getting two errors -

`ERROR: Exception(/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/component-prefix-blah-api-proxy/blah-api-proxy/SRPMS/component-prefix-blah-api-proxy-0.1.0.15-1.bbc.el7.src.rpm) Config(epel-7-x86_64) 0 minutes 11 seconds`
and

```
 # bash --login -c /usr/bin/rpmbuild -bb --target x86_64 --nodeps /builddir/build/SPECS/blah-api-proxy.spec
```

```
Version: 0.1.0%{?BUILD_NUMBER:.%{BUILD_NUMBER}}
Release: 1%{?dist}
Group: System Environment/Daemons
License: Internal COY use only
Summary: BLAH API Proxy
Source0: src.tar.gz
Requires: blah-blah-ssl-services-blah-staff jq
BuildRoot: %(mktemp -ud %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-XXXXXX)
BuildArch: x86_64

%description
BLAH API Proxy

%prep
%setup -q -n src

%build

%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}
cp -r * %{buildroot}/

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}

%pre

%files
%defattr(0755, root, root, 0755)
/var/www/cgi-bin/*

%defattr(-, root, root, 0755)
/etc/bake-scripts/*

%defattr(0755, root, root, 0755)
/etc/bake-scripts/blah-api-proxy
```

N.B: `blah-api-proxy` is a directory containing Apache proxy server configurations.

The src folder structure is as follows:

```
src/
├── etc
│   └── bake-scripts
│       ├── blah-api-proxy
│       └── public-endpoints
└── var
    └── www
        └── cgi-bin
```

I will be very grateful if I get help in resolving this issue.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You will need to post the actual failure, not the summary saying it failed.

Comment: Right, this is just mock stating which command failed. The error from the command is a few lines above this one. Without that, we cannot help you.

Comment: Hello @AaronD.Marasco,  I am so sorry that I did not post this. I am new to RPM builds and only just looked through the Jenkins log to see that the main RPM errors are logged to a build.log file. I have updated the post above with it.

Comment: Hello @msuchy, I am so sorry that I did not post this. I am new to RPM builds and only just looked through the Jenkins log to see that the main RPM errors are logged to a build.log file. I have updated the post above with it.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco, from the error above, it looks like it cannot find the files under the directory /var/www/cgi-bin/* that are specified by the wildcard or glob. Is there a better way to specify wildcards? Would replacing * with . here work?

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco, after careful examination and the use of an older commit that had fewer files under the %files sectin, I noticed that the /var/ folder was not being pushed to our git upstream branch. This led to discovering that someone had added an entry for that folder in the .gitignore file. I now have a successful build in Jenkins and on the way to have a fully working deployment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am very thankful to @msuchy for his help with this problem. His recommendation helped me in identifying the root cause quickly.

The problem was that one of the directories, `/var/`, specified in the `%files` section of the `spec file` was excluded from the git repo by the `.gitignore` file. Removing the directory from the `.gitignore` file solved this problem

The other thing that was required which we did was specify the rpm repositories that our spec file relied on, in our release system (not Jenkins).

Answer (score 0):

The error state (during processing %files section) that `%{buildroot}/var/www/cgi-bin/`
does not exist.

So you *think* that you copy something, but the reality is different.

Add at the end of `%install` section: `find %{buildroot}/` and run the build again, and you will see what `cp` actually put there.

Comment: Thank you @msuchy. I did that and saw that all the files were copied to the %{buildroot}/ directory. Why is it then failing?

Comment: Mind you, I am not setting the ```--old-chroot flag``` this time around. I shared the build.log excerpts for the build is run without that flag set.

Comment: After careful examination and the use of an older commit that had fewer files under the %files sectin, I noticed that the /var/ folder was not being pushed to our git upstream branch. This led to discovering that someone had added an entry for that folder in the .gitignore file. I now have a successful build in Jenkins and on the way to have a fully working deployment.